# how to ssh to user@host in python?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

```
import paramiko

host = "172.21.14.48"
port = 22
username = "user"
password = "xxx*9841"
command = "ls"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password )
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
lines = stdout.readlines()
print(lines)
```

This code works SSH successful. But I need to ssh to cp@172.21.14.48  with same username and password.

```
Using username "cp".
Keyboard-interactive authentication prompts from server:
Actual Username:
Actual Password:
```

I tried below code but getting error.

```
host = "cp@172.21.14.48"
```

Error message as:

> File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\socket.py", line
> 918, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno 11003] getaddrinfo failed

However with PuTTY I can ssh to cp@172.21.14.48. Any suggestion..?

Answer (score 1):

The `cp` in the `ssh cp@172.21.14.48` is a *username*, so it goes to the `username` argument of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect):

```
username = "cp"
# ...
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect(host, port, username, password)
```

---

Your server prompts for another set of credentials using keyboard interactive authentication.
For that see: [Password authentication in Python Paramiko fails, but same credentials work in SSH/SFTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55498370/850848)
You have to adjust the code to answer both the second username and password prompts. The `fields` parameter of the handler will have two entries and the handler has to return a two answers in its result.