# What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, cisco

So what is the difference between `SSHClient.exec_command()` and send with `SSHClient.invoke_shell` on Paramiko?

I can send and execute command with `exec_command` to MikroTik router device but can't execute it with `send` (`invoke_shell()`).

On the other hand, I can send and execute command `send` (`invoke_shell()`) to Cisco device, but can't execute it with `exec_command`.

The command I mean is the configuration command like routing (ip route xxx xxx) or make vlan or add an ip address and etc..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is that `invoke_shell` uses SSH `shell` channel, while `exec_command` uses SSH `exec` channel.

What that really means to you as a user/developer really depends on the SSH server, not on Paramiko itself.

---

In common *nix OpenSSH server:

- The `shell` channel executes a login shell (as if you login with SSH terminal client). The shell will then present a command prompt and wait for client/user to type the commands. The purpose of the `shell` channel is to implement an interactive shell session. So basically it's legitimate use is an implementation of an SSH terminal client. That is something one will do very very rarely. If you do, you typically want to use [terminal emulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) (Paramiko `invoke_shell` does that unconditionally, but actually it's possible to open the `shell` channel without the terminal emulation).

  The `shell` channel is obviously used by SSH terminal clients (like OpenSSH `ssh` or PuTTY), under normal circumstances.

  The `shell` channel is a black box with an input and output. The input and output have no structure. If you for example execute a command by sending it to the input, you will never be able to tell when it ended. If you send two commands to input queue, you won't be able to distinguish what output comes from what command.
- The `exec` command takes a command as an "argument" and executes it in an isolated environment – still via user's default shell, but not as a "login" shell, what may cause significant differences in the command execution.

  For a typical example of such difference, see [Some Unix commands fail with "<command> not found", when executed using Python Paramiko exec_command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55419330/850848).

  The purpose of the `exec` channel is automating a command execution. So typically you do not want to use a terminal emulation, to avoid the command to do fancy stuff like pagination, coloring and mainly interactive confirmations. That's why the default value of `get_pty` is `False`.

  The `exec` channel is used by OpenSSH `ssh` or PuTTY `plink`, when you specify a command to execute on its command line:

  ```
  ssh user@host command
  ```

---

With less common SSH servers, the difference can be even more significant. Some servers may even not support one of the channels. It is also quite common that they seemingly support both, but one of them (typically the `exec`) is completely broken.

See [Executing command using Paramiko exec_command on device is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30603219/850848).

---

There's a similar question for Java/JSch:
[What is the difference between the 'shell' channel and the 'exec' channel in JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6770206/850848)