# Paramiko stdout.readlines() vs channel.recv()

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, pexpect

I'm new to python paramiko. I know there are two ways to execute a command in a remote server `invokde_shell` and `exec_command`. In few cases the output is read using `stdout.readlines()` whereas in other cases using `channel.recv` with `exit_status` as loop condition. It is very difficult to understand the difference between both and which one to use for my script. Can anyone please explain ?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather broad question, so only briefly:
`readlines` vs `recv` – This is nothing Paramiko-specific. You have the same set of functions, when reading local files or local program input. Use whatever fits your needs. If you need to read by bytes (e.g. when processing a binary input), you probably want to use `recv` (or `read`). If you want to process a textual input by lines, use `readlines` (or `readline`).

You also mix in shell vs. exec into your question, what is a separate stuff, covered here:
[What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848)

---

*Overall, you better ask a specific question about implementing your specific problem.*