# Run remote long running command with Paramiko, feed it with some input and put it to the background

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I have a long running program on my remote server, which I want to start with Paramiko.

I know how to start a program in the background (with `nohup` for example) but my program first needs a few user inputs. In a normal SSH session I would pass those interactively over the terminal and then detach (<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, `bg`, `detach`) but I can't do this with Paramiko.

Here is what I've been trying so far:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('MyCommand', get_pty=True)
stdin.channel.send(b'MyData\r')
stdin.channel.send(b'\x1A')  # This is Ctrl+Z
ssh.exec_command('bg; disown')
ssh.close()
```

but when the SSH connection closes, the remote program also stops running. How can I send user input to a program, that I want to continue running in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently executing `MyCommand` and `bg; disown` in two separate shell instances. That's why the `bg; disown` has no effect on the `MyCommand`.

If you really want to emulate the interactive shell features this way, them you need to execute both command in one real shell instance. For that you will need to use [`SSHClient.invoke_shell`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.invoke_shell) and not `SSHClient.exec_command`.

---

Though in general, that's not a good idea. See also:
[What is the difference between exec_command and send with invoke_shell() on Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848)

If the program is yours, modify it to allow getting input from command-line.

If you cannot modify it, use shell constructs to provide the input, like:

```
ssh.exec_command('nohup echo MyData | MyCommand >/dev/null 2>&1 &')
```

Maybe you need to add quotes around the command, I'm not sure, what's the "operator precedence" here.

Comment: Using invoke_shell works well for my usecase. Thanks.