# Python Paramiko - problems with sending "iperf -s" to Linux server

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I need to send the command `iperf -s` to a Linux server using a Python program. The command is not sent. The chronology of problems is as follows:

1. I am sending the command `iperf -s` to the server. Nothing happens, the program freezes (I don't stop the program).
2. I use the `netstat -tupln` to check the processes. A process `iperf` is created on the server, but nothing is happened.
3. If I kill this process with a `sudo kill -9 <PID>`, the program outputs the traditional output when the `iperf -s` is executed and the program exits.
4. If I check the processes again, the `iperf` process is not there.

Here's my code:

```
remote_server = "172.22.94.171"
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
username = "useruser"
password = "password"

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(remote_server, port=22, username=username, password=password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('sudo iperf -s', get_pty=True)

stdin.write(password+'\n')

print(stdout.readlines())
```

Comment: If you `sudo strace -p <PID>` on the iperf process, what is it doing at the time of the freeze?

Comment: @NickODell 
The program still freezes. The server displays this when entering the command:
futex(0x55565cdf71a8, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 0, NULL, FUTEX_BITSET_MATCH_ANY

If I stop the program, the server displays the following:
--- SIGHUP {si_signo=SIGHUP, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=3397, si_uid=1001} ---
+++ killed by SIGHUP +++

Comment: What happens if you do `ssh -t useruser@172.22.94.171 sudo iperf -s` (as a **single**  line)?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl nothing. PID is not created, program freeze

Comment: So the same behaviour as with Paramiko? (it should be, as this command is equivalent to what you are doing with Paramiko)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl if I run this command on server, iperf is running as usual

Comment: Ok, but your Python code does the same as `ssh -t useruser@172.22.94.171 sudo iperf -s`. So if that does not work, your Python code cannot not work either. If `iperf` must be executed from shell (but does it really?), then you need to use `invoke_shell`, not `exec_command`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/55762006/850848.